# Can I disable a button next to the button I press?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to disable 2 buttons at one click, without specifying these buttons. I have ~150 buttons on my form, and I dont want to write a function for all of them.

I have a function something like this, to disable a button I click on.

```
public void disableButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((Button)sender).Enabled == true)
    {
        ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
        ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

So basically, when I call this function, I would like to disable THIS button, and a button next to it. **(Eg. button1 and button2)**

Comment: You're gonna have to define what "next to it" exactly means. After you do, the solution will become obvious to you.

Comment: Do the button names follow a pattern of any sort? How do you actually calculate / know what button is "next to it" is it simply if you click button3 that it is button4? If you can clarify this we can help further.

Comment: If I click 'Button1', "next to it" there will be 'Button2'. So actually yes, they have a pattern. Always '+1' from the other button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the button should be added in the control in a specific order, so that when you will get all the buttons based on your requirement you can disable the immediate next button to the current button, Kindly refer to below code:

```
public void disableButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           var selectedButton = ((Button)sender);
           var allButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
           var currentButtonIndex = allButtons.Select((s, i) => new { button = s, index = i }).Single(si => si.button.Name == selectedButton.Name).index;
           if (allButtons[currentButtonIndex + 1].Enabled == true)
           {
               allButtons[currentButtonIndex + 1].Enabled = false;
               allButtons[currentButtonIndex + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
           }
}
```

To get list of all buttons in your form `Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList()`, next step is to get the index of current button. Once you get the index the increment it with 1 and you will get the reference of the next button
for safer implementation just check if it is not the last button in that case choose the first button, refer below code:

```
currentButtonIndex = currentButtonIndex + 1 >= allButtons.Count() ? 0 : currentButtonIndex;
```

Suppose you are not able to figure out the ordering of the buttons, but the next button should be based on `TabStop`, based on `TabStop` you can better find the next button, refer below code

```
var allButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>().OrderBy(o => o.TabStop).ToList();
var currentButtonIndex =  allButtons.Select((s, i) => new { button = s, index = i }).Single(si => si.button.Name == selectedButton.Name).index;
var toDisableButton = allButtons[currentButtonIndex + 1];
Controls.OfType<Button>().Single(si => si.Name == toDisableButton.Name).Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a collection of pairs, where pair: (name_of_btn_1, name_of_btn_2).
   This can be an `IDictionary<string, string>`.
2. Inside the click event handler, get the associated button name using the dictionary. Then, you can do [this.Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_) to get the associated button by name and disable it.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to keep two references on the two buttons rather than a dictionnary...?

Comment: It's ~150 buttons buddy. Besides this is just an alternative solution. Amit's answer is better (assuming the indexing is in the right order, but it can be fixed).